# Is it possible to copy a work item in TFS 2010 from one project to another under same server? like http://sbn-mdx-wxe01:8080/tfs by C# code

Tags: c#, tfs

I need to create a tool in C# in which a work item of one project could be copied to another project. We are using TFS 2010.

1. Is it possible? So far I could not find any solution on net.
2. If possible then could someone help me how is it possible in C#?

Comment: Not usually.  Servers when connected by http give clients GUEST privileges that do not allow clients access to the file system.  The application that does the copying would need to use Admin privileges which is not a good idea accept under very limited conditions.  If you need to copy files you can make a 2nd app running As Admin on server to give limited access to GUESTS.  Or put files in a Network drives where you can give more access to users.

Comment: in tfs 2010 I have seen that there is a copy option for any work item to copy in to another project. so when it is possible to copy work item from one project to other then it could be done in C# possibly. I got confused what you explained. I have admin access to all project like source to destination projects. So i request you please help me out if you can. If not possible give me a valid reason with example . or if its possible then tell how could it be done.

Comment: Copy only works when user has access to both source and destination folders/files.  So where are the project files stored?  The TFS application can be on the server and the project files stored locally on client machine which would give access to the project files.

Comment: @jdweng You are confusing the issue. The question is about **work items**, not files. The answer to the question is "no, you can't do that in TFS 2010." It's time to consider upgrading.

Comment: A file is a file is a file.   Doesn't matter if it is a project file or any other file.

Comment: @jdweng There are **no files** involved in this question in any way, shape, or form. Work items are not files. You may not be familiar with the problem domain, which is TFS. A TFS project is not the same thing as a C# project.

Comment: What do you thing the following is? Vapor Ware "copy a work item in TFS 2010 from one project  another"  A work item is a file.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for c# Client libraries for TFS, you can check out `Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.Client`

You can use the [GetWorkItem](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.teamfoundation.workitemtracking.webapi.workitemtrackinghttpclientbase.getworkitemasync?view=azure-devops-dotnet) method to get the detailed data of the workitem. And then use [CreateWorkItem](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.teamfoundation.workitemtracking.webapi.workitemtrackinghttpclientbase.createworkitemasync?view=azure-devops-dotnet) method to create a new workitem with the workitem data in another project.

Since you are using the tfs2010, You can start tring with the oldest version of the client library to see if it works with tfs2010. If it doesnot work with tfs2010, you need to consider upgrading your tfs2010 to the version which is supported by the client library.

See document [.NET client libraries for Azure DevOps and TFS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/integrate/concepts/dotnet-client-libraries?view=azure-devops) for more information.

I found an example [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2013/bb130322(v=vs.120)) to create workitem using the an old version client library. You can check it out.

Hope above helps!